# Convert Tuple of Date and list into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of tuple and I want to convert it into a dataframe. I am doing like something this:

```
a = (date1, [1,2,3,4,5,6]) 
frame = pandas.DataFrame(a)
```

Also I write this to a csv file:

```
frame.to_csv('frame.csv', sep = ',', encoding='utf-8')
```

But the problem is that it writes in the csv file like the following:

```
0         | 1
date1     | [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want it to write like this.

```
0         | 1   |2    |3    |4    |5    |6
date1     | 1   |2    |3    |4    |5    |6
```

How can I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a list of tuples, then try doing `pd.DataFrame(dict(a)).T`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create DataFrame from `list` by convert first item of tuple to one item list `[a[0]]` and add it to nested list `a[1]`:

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
a = (date1, [1,2,3,4,5,6]) 

L = [a[0]] + a[1]
print (L)
[Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

frame = pd.DataFrame([L])
print (frame)
           0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0 2015-01-01  1  2  3  4  5  6
```